# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Erro Query

Error: 
"Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'."

my cod

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string connectionString = GetCString();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO Sys_Users_Detail(Money) VALUES ('{0}'), where NickName ('{1}')", textBox20.Text, textBox19.Text);
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Logger.getS().info_pc(string.Format("Foi Enviado : {0} Cps , Para : {1}", textBox20.Text, textBox19.Text));
            }


        }
    }
```

Error Query:

```
"INSERT INTO Sys_Users_Detail(Money) VALUES ('{0}'), where NickName ('{1}')"
```

Comment: Dude, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: `INSERT` just doesn't support a `WHERE` clause, as the [official SQL Server documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - freely available to **everyone** - clearly shows ....

Comment: Why did you tagged your question C#, if you have problem with SQL query? You would get the same error, when you execute that query using any language or even manually. You should always localize and isolate your problem. Once you fix your query, so you can execute it manually, you should integrate it into your program and check if it works there.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want `insert`?  You most likely want to `update`

```
 UPDATE Sys_Users_Detail
        SET Money = {0}
        WHERE NickName = '{1}'
```

I assume that `Money` is a decimal value so you should not have quotes around the value.

Also by using `string.Format` you are open to a **SQL injection attack**.  Use [SqlParameter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to avoid an attack.

Comment: No, that is not correct. INSERT statement cannot have a WHERE clause.

Comment: @Jonathon The answer was changed after my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid INSERT statement. 1) INSERT cannot have a WHERE clause. 2) The `money` column is probably numeric so the value should not be quoted.
Also this is good example candidate for SQL injection - see comment below question.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid `INSERT` query. It looks like you're trying to update a value based on `NickName`, which isn't what `INSERT` is for.

If that's the case, try:

```
UPDATE Sys_Users_Detail
SET Money = '{0}'
WHERE NickName = '{1}'
```

Answer (score -2):

**query has to be in INSERT 
query has to be in INSERT 
query has to be in INSERT 
query has to be in INSERT**

Comment: What does it mean? "Insert" is a type of query, so how can be query in an insert?